# RabbitMQ - How to open the 5672 port on aws console correctly

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, rabbitmq

I have my rabbitMQ setup in an aws ec2 instance which is in a private subnet, i'm able to access it's management console and perform operations as well.
But when i'm trying to connect to the rabbitmq via node.js, using aqmp:// , I get an error

**2022-08-16 08:39:20.081458+00:00 [error] <0.31050.1> {bad_header,<<"GET / HT">>}**

I have a load balancer facing the internet and I have opened HTTP traffic on ports 5672 and 15672, am I doing something wrong here ? in terms of ports ?

Should these ports be TCP ?

Comment: rabbitMQ is probably not http. You can try with NLB.

Comment: You probably shouldn't be using a load balancer at all. I don't think RabbitMQ is designed to run behind a load balancer.

Comment: I'm having this same issue using Rabbit and NodeJS (amqplib package).  Was the issue due to the load balancer?

Answer (score 0):

Try to open the PORT in your SecurityGroup in AWS if you use some instance ec2

Answer (score -2):

The information is not that clear. It's better to describe the architecture more clear. According to the information we've got here. I assume that the architecture will look like the picture [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gdnsd.jpg). If it's the case, since you can access the RMQ management console which means you have give the local access(like your local ip address) to the port 5672. but fail to access this port from node.js server. Therefore, I guess you'd better to check have you opened the access for ip address A which is the ip address for node.js. Please make sure the node.js, all the consumers have the access. [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dO9Nj.png). All the operations happens in the security group.

Comment: He is asking how to do that.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).